# Cannot enter dot or characters in a textbox which is placed on a datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am implementing a custom filter for datagridview.
The custom Filter is a user control which has a textbox that allows the user to enter text.

When the user selects a particular column for filtering, I am adding the filter usercontrol to the Grid controls and then displaying it just below the selected column.

Issue :
When the user tries to enter the filter text on to the textbox, it accepts only numerical values and characters, it does not allow dots or certian characters like !" . however if the user clicks on the delete key, from then onwards the textbox accepts all input characters.

This is probably to do with the fact that the user control is added to the Grid's control collection, and the grid is consuming these events in a different way..?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code from your filter?

Comment: Hi Stuart, this happens when i simply place a textbox over a grid and add it to the gird's Control collection. The grid in question however was a cutom datagridview derived from windows datagridview. I tried changing the grid back to the Windows one, it does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the control to grid's control collection, but to the form's or container's collection - Then just call the filter control's BringToFront() when you want to show the control in front of the datagrid, and when done with filtering just call Hide() or SendToBack() so it goes non visible again.